# Why can't I compile Ruby on RHEL 6?

Tags: ruby, compilation, configure

I'm attempting to compile Ruby on a RHEL 6 server.  I have the source code on my box locally (v2.4.1) and have attempted to run `./configure` from the source code root directory.  However the 'configure' script is returning the following:-

```
[root@mysrvr ruby-2.4.1]# ./configure
checking for ruby... false
 differs from program version 2.4
```

What is strange is that it appears the script is checking for the existence of Ruby, and stopping because it's not found (I'm inferring that based on the output).  But Ruby is what I'm trying to compile/install. `Chicken/Egg`:-

How would I have Ruby if that's the very thing I'm trying to get on my system?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following link that explains it.  Essentially, starting with Ruby 1.9, they made it a requirement to have Ruby in order to compile.  Strange, but true...

https://serverfault.com/questions/291493/centos-ruby-executable-host-ruby-is-required